# Rails 7 ./bin/importmap command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I created a new Rails 7 application (rails 7.0.4 and Ruby 3.0.4) and tried to use the importmap command to create a pin entry for jquery in config/importmap.rb.  The command comes back immediately and there is no entry for jquery in importmap.rb.

Here's the command I ran and what comes back in the terminal:

```
C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Work\work\railsprojects\rails7a> ./bin/importmap pin jquery

 C:\Users\Owner\Documents\My Work\work\railsprojects\rails7a>
```

Here's the contents of config/importmap.rb:

```
# Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

As you can see, there is no pin for jquery, which is what I expected to see in this file.

I don't understand why it's not working.  Does anyone know why the importmap command is not working for me and how I can get it to work properly?  Thanks.

Comment: You try run `bin/importmap pin jquery`. I used this command

Comment: Hi Lihn, thanks for the suggestion, but running bin/importmap pin jquery does not work either.